# Modelica - Stop Blocks from Triggering Events

Tags: events, modelica

I've got a unitDelays scattered through a model in OpenModelica that generate events and therefore cause an output line to be generated. This overrides my output interval setting which is far less frequent. My unitDelays need to be one second intervals, but I only want to save every hour.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the block `Modelica.Blocks.Discrete.UnitDelay.UnitDelay`. This block will always generate events, that's the fundamental working principle of it.

However, you can disable storing output values at events in the simulation setup.

[image]

The default setting is to store all values with the configured time grid *and* for every event point.